# jQuery .change() event is not being triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange

Example is at http://jsfiddle.net/4RAPH/ or see below:

```
<select class="businessTypePullDown">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Business Type</option>
    <option value="1">General</option>
    <option value="2">Lawyer</option>
    <option value="3">Software Development</option>
    <option value="4">Auto-repair</option>
</select>

function filterPullDown () {
    alert('hello');
}

$("businessTypePullDown").change(filterPullDown);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a typo, you missed a dot:

```
 $(".businessTypePullDown")
```

Your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/4RAPH/1/

Comment: Major, Major Epic Facepalm. Thank you.

Comment: Not so epic, it may happens especially after 8 working hours. :)

Comment: Had one myself yesterday, spelled visible wrong...

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?